# How to send mail through more person from this code?

Tags: c#, window, gmail, sendmail

I'm trying to send email with attachments to more then hundred people at once, and I find very good source code which working perfect with attachs but can't send mails to more than one man at once.

So now my question is: Can you help me modify existing code to make that work?

Programming language: C#

Here is code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{

    public class GmailAccount
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
        public string DisplayName;

        public string Address
        {
            get
            {
                return Username + "@gmail.com";
            }
        }

        private SmtpClient client;

        public GmailAccount(string username, string password, string displayName = null)
        {
            Username = username;
            Password = password;
            DisplayName = displayName;

            client = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Address, password)
            };
        }

        public void SendMessage(string targetAddress, string subject, string body, params string[] files)
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(Address, DisplayName), new MailAddress(targetAddress))
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body
            };

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(file);
                message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }

            client.Send(message);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GmailAccount acc = new GmailAccount("username", "password", "Caption");
            acc.SendMessage("some.person@gmail.com", "Hello World!", "like in the title...", "C:\\temp.rar");
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: hello wanna be spambot number 10230920 :P unless youre only mailing people that WANT to be mailed and sign up for it, dont expect much help its been asked so many times here :P

Comment: Many thing ... i work on similar code from my self but have problem with sending more than one attach..

Comment: john his point was show us what youve already tried, or atleast tell us, so we can say why its not working...

Comment: @RhysW im understand that, but im new in c# so i'm searching for some healp or good tutorial to solve problem ...

Comment: @John Getting someone to do everything for you and copy/pasting entire programs is entirely different from learning a language.  If you make not attempt, and only ask someone to solve every tiny problem you have then you aren't learning anything.

Comment: even in the related section down the right hand side of this question there are hundreds of things there. no matter how new to c# you are you should have a basic understanding of using search engines to search :P

Comment: So what's in `C:\temp.rar`? A trojan horse or virus? Well, just kidding, but mass mailing compressed attachments is something hackers and spammers do a lot so your code looks a bit dodgy.

Comment: @Martin glad youre thinking along the same lines as me :D

Comment: @MartinLiversage temp.rar is zipped file ... i didn't put .txt file cause i know that can be sended in every case, .rar doesnt work every case ....

Comment: @RhysW man if you don't help, i please you that also do not make things hard

Comment: John i have provided an addition in the comments to some of the answers on ways to achieve what youre trying to do, im not just being annoying i do provide help where possible too :P like also pointing out all the helpful hundreds of links down the right hand side of this topic, technically i provided more help than anyone else here ;)

Comment: @RhysW ok thnx, i'm new in c#, so i know that i have some hole in education but i don't have much time to learn at now, .. cause application have to be finished very soon ... that is why i ask for help, not for other purpose ... have to go see you

Comment: in which case combine my suggestion of using a loop with the answer given by Josh Mein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass more value splited with comma in targetAddress parameter of SendMessage.

Sample code to send mail to multiple persons:

```
public bool SendEmail()
{
    bool status = false;

        try
        {
            //code to send email
            this._mail = new MailMessage();

            this._mail.From = new MailAddress(this.From, this.DisplayName);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.To))
            {
                var distinctAddress = new List<string>(this.To.Split(',').Distinct());
                this.To = string.Empty;

                foreach (string address in distinctAddress) // Loop through all strings
                {
                    this.To += address + ","; // Append string to StringBuilder
                }
                this.To = this.To.TrimEnd(',');
                this._mail.To.Add(this.To);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CC))
                this._mail.CC.Add(this.CC);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.BCC))
                this._mail.Bcc.Add(this.BCC);

            this._mail.Subject = this.Subject;

            this._mail.IsBodyHtml = this.IsBodyHtml;

            this._mail.Body = this.Body;

            if (this.Priority == true)
            {
                this._mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            }

            this._mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

            if (this._attachments != null && this._attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in this._attachments)
                {
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(file);
                    this._mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                }
            }

            this._smtpServer = new SmtpClient(this.EmailServer);
            this._smtpServer.EnableSsl = this.EnableSsl;
            this._smtpServer.Port = this.Port;
            this._smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(this.UserId, this.Password);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.To) != true || string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CC) != true || string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.BCC) != true)
                this._smtpServer.Send(this._mail);
            status = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* way to teach the new guy to do things himself instead of relying on everyone else to do it for him :P

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("test@gmail.com");
```

Comment: he would be better off with a list containing an entire set of the hundreds of people he wants to mail and iterating through a loop where "test@gmail.com" is i where i is both the loop count and the list number to pick then running through til it reaches the end of the list, using your code inside the loop with the one change i suggested :) (not taking you apart, adding to your answer to make it more useful)

Comment: I agree. Since he didnt put much effort into his question, I did not want to give him everything.